# Why is my Node.js App not showing on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mobile

I created a Realtime Visitor Counter App in Node.js and got it deployed to my website. The Visitor Counter works perfectly on desktop but, does not show on mobile devices.

[Click Here for Realtime Visitor Counter Example](https://detroitskydaddy.com/pages/video-counter-test-iframe)

Below I included **two code snippets**, the current code for my "App.js" file, and the Script in the apps "Index.html"

**App.js File Code**

```
/* app.js */

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');

app.use(cors()); // Prevents CORS error

app.get('/api', function(req, res) {

    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.end();
    } 
    // Ends request for favicon without counting

    const json = fs.readFileSync('count.json', 'utf-8');
    const obj = JSON.parse(json);
    // Reads count.json and converts to JS object

    obj.pageviews = obj.pageviews+1;
    if (req.query.type === 'visit-pageview') {
        obj.visits = obj.visits+1;
    }
    // Updates pageviews and visits (conditional upon URL param value)

    const newJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
    // Converts result to JSON

    fs.writeFileSync('count.json', newJSON);
    res.send(newJSON);
    // Writes result to file and sends to user as JSON

})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server running on port 3000");
})
```

**Below is the JS code snippet in the index.html file of the app.**

```
  <script>

const pageviewsCount = document.getElementById('pageviews-count');
const visitsCount = document.getElementById('visits-count');

if (sessionStorage.getItem('visit') === null) {
  // New visit and pageview
  updateCounter('type=visit-pageview');
} else {
  // Pageview
  updateCounter('type=pageview');
}

function updateCounter(type) {

  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api?'+type) // Dynamic request with URL parameter
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      pageviewsCount.textContent = data.pageviews; // Display pageviews to user
      visitsCount.textContent = data.visits; // Display visits to user
    })

}

sessionStorage.setItem('visit', 'x');
// 'visit' item persists in storage for the remainder of the user session

  </script>
```